# CakePHP controller usando funções de outro controller

Tags: php, cakephp

Tenho 2 tabelas: cliente e email.

Ao salvar o cliente, preciso salvar o email junto à tabela de email, porém preciso chamar a função `save` do controller dos emails.

Como faço?

Answer (score 0):

Para usar uma model de outra controller, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
public function add() {
    ...
    Controller::loadModel('EmailModel');
    $this->EmailModel->save(...);
}
```

Comment: me explica, o Controller::loadModel('EmailModel'); eu colo onde?

Comment: Dentro do método que você for utilizar a model (de exemplo) "EmailModel". Por exemplo, dentro do seu método `add()`

Comment: colei e ficou assim:
Controller::loadModel('Email');
            $email="erre@uol.com.br";
            $this->Email->save($email);
mas ainda dá erro no "Controller::loadModel('Email');"
o erro que mostra é "Class 'App\Controller\Controller' not found"
mesmo tentando chamar o "use App\Controller\Controller;"
ainda dá erro...

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar que esse código deve ser colocado dentro da Controller, não na Model. Está fazendo isso na Controller, certo?

Comment: sim , no controller

Comment: Por via das dúvidas, adicione isso ao começo da sua controller `App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');`

Comment: coloquei e apareceu o erro "Class 'App\Controller\App' not found" a minha versão do cake é essa mais nova...faz muita diferença?

Comment: Possivelmente. Experimente utilizar a função `$this->loadModel('Email')`, como na documentação: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/pt/controllers.html#carregando-models-adicionais

Answer (score 0):

No inicio do controller tem que colocar:

use Cake\Controller\Controller;

E no método cololar o: Controller::loadModel('nome_model');

Depois que coloquei isso o erro sumiu.